# Testing AngularJS express node app

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, angularjs, mocha.js, zombie.js

I have an issue with testing my application with both `jasmine-node` and `mocha` (with `zombie`). The point is `angular` doesn't work with this test environment - when `browser.visit "http://localhost:3000/"` it displays only layout, and don't render any templates [link](https://gist.github.com/3303382). I guess javascript doesn't run in browser (I mean zombie object) at all. [My test](https://github.com/zishe/angular-express-coffee/blob/master/test/app_test.coffee) Is there any way to make it works? Or problem is different?

In jasmine spec that i copied from another project [spec](https://github.com/zishe/angular-express-coffee/blob/master/spec/app_spec.coffee) occures an error:

```
/home/alder/Node/angular-express-coffee/spec/app_spec.coffee:12
        throw error;
              ^
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at /js/services.js:4:3
    at /js/services.js:6:4
    in /js/services.js
```

So I guess javascript doesn't work too.

Update:
I add debug option and here what it displays:

```
➜  angular-express-coffee git:(master) ✗ mocha --require should --compilers coffee:coffee-script --colors  -R spec --ui bdd


  Given I am a new user
    When I visit the home page
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/newPost => 200
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/ => 200
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/lib/angular.min.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/app.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/controllers.js => 200
Zombie: Unexpected token ILLEGAL SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    in /js/controllers.js
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js => 200
Zombie: Unexpected token ILLEGAL SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    in /js/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/filters.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/directives.js => 200
Zombie: Unexpected token ILLEGAL SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    in /js/directives.js
Zombie: Unexpected token ILLEGAL SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    in /js/filters.js
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js => 200
Zombie: Unexpected token ILLEGAL SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    in /js/lib/bootstrap.min.js
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/lib/angular.min.js => 200
Zombie: Unexpected token ILLEGAL SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    in /js/lib/angular.min.js
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/services.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/filters.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/directives.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/controllers.js => 200
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/app.js => 200
Zombie: Unexpected token ILLEGAL SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    in /js/app.js
Zombie: Unexpected token ILLEGAL SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    in /js/controllers.js
Zombie: Unexpected token ILLEGAL SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    in /js/directives.js
Zombie: Unexpected token ILLEGAL SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    in /js/filters.js
Zombie: GET http://localhost:3000/js/services.js => 200
```

Perhaps the problem in coffeescript but i had add option to mocha. And is there any method to test angular apps without JsTestDriver propagated by Angular team.

Updated.
I had changed errors assertions to `browser.errors.should.be.empty` and it had shown me an error:

```
1) Given I am a new user When I visit the home page Then browser status shold be ok:
AssertionError: expected [ [Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL],
  [Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL],
  [Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL],
  [Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL],
  [Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL],
  [Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL],
  [Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL],
  [Error: angular is not defined] ] to be empty
  at Object.empty (/home/alder/Node/angular-express-coffee/node_modules/should/lib/should.js:229:10)
  at Context.<anonymous> (/home/alder/Node/angular-express-coffee/test/app_test.coffee:31:40)
  at Test.Runnable.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:184:32)
  at Runner.runTest (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:300:10)
  at Runner.runTests.next (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:346:12)
  at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:228:14)
  at Runner.hooks (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:237:7)
  at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:185:23)
  at Runner.hook (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:205:5)
  at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Last update:
The problem was in assets pipeline, all `js` was disabled for `Zombie` browser. Now I change to js from coffee and it works. But I prefer coffee, So if anyone can solve it, i'll be grateful.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "js was disabled for Zombie"? I have the exact same issue, and the only fix I found was to use `express.static` to serve JS files (not ideal).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700152/express-js-and-zombie-js-cant-seem-to-parse-javascript-assets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [Angular Scenario Runner](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing)?

Answer (score 2):

Can it be because of Mocha? I hear it can cause problems because of its name...