# Express.js and Zombie.js - Can't seem to parse Javascript assets

Tags: node.js, express, gzip, zombie.js, node.js-connect

I have an Express.js app that uses `connect-asssets` to serve JS and CSS:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.set('port', 3000);
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(connectAssets({src: path.join(__dirname, 'assets')}));
});
```

I'm trying to use [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org) for acceptance testing, but keep getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` whenever it tries to parse a Javascript file. If I replace `connect-assets` with `express.static`, then the acceptance tests work perfectly.

Any idea what `connect-assets` does differently that would trip up Zombie.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ran the requests through [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com). Zombie sends the request header `Accept-Encoding: identity`, but `connect-assets` returns GZIP data anyway.

I [raised an issue](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-file-cache/issues/8) with `connect-file-cache` on Github, hopefully everything will run fine once this is fixed.